# unable to rid recursive parsing code of shared_ptr leaks

Tags: c++11, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I am using shared_ptrs extensively in my production code mainly to reduce complexity and maintenance and it generally is working fine. I have, however, written a parser for a complex meta-grammar that leaves shared objects upon exit. One of the culprits is caused by recursivity. Since the parsing code is complex in itself, I want to re-use it each time I descend to the next level. Consequently, I save off the current element in its parent's element while doing descendent parsing. But this causes the problem of too many remaining strong refs. I have experimented a good bit with weak vs strong storing and the TreeVect uses weak_ptrs, but the parent assignment problem persists. My question is, how can I get rid of the second strong ref that gets added on the assignment to the parent statement below? Here is code that illustrates my problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Tree;
typedef std::weak_ptr< Tree > TreeWptr;
typedef std::shared_ptr< Tree > TreeSptr;
typedef std::vector< TreeWptr > TreeVect;

struct Tree
{
  TreeVect treeVect;
  //TreeSptr parent;
  TreeWptr parent; // changed from strong to weak ptr
};

struct Element1 : public Tree
{
};

struct Element2 : public Tree
{
};


int main()
{
  TreeSptr element1 = std::make_shared< Element1 >();
  TreeSptr element2 = std::make_shared< Element2 >();
  //element2->parent = element1; // illustrates recursive case.  ERROR: Adds extra strong ref to element1
  //element2->parent->treeVect.push_back( element2 );
  element2->parent = element1; // no longer adds extra strong ref to element1
  element2->parent.lock()->treeVect.push_back( element2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I solved this example program's problem by changing the parent member from a shared_ptr to a weak_ptr.

Comment: `shared_ptr` rarely makes resource management simpler.  `unique_ptr` makes things simpler, but explicitly won't let you do the above.  In any case, your question fails to actually ask a question.

Comment: I added the question to my OP test.

Comment: There is no recursion of the data structure in the above code.  Your real code is thus going to be different.  When you are being recursive like that, do you know you are being recursive like that?  As your leaves seem to keep their parents around (and not the other way around), what should happen if the leaf that remains has a parent pointer that isn't a strong ref?  Your general problem remains: you think `shared_ptr`s simplify lifetime management.  They don't in general.

Comment: That's a fairly broad assertion that the smart pointer, that is, reference counted technique used for the new c++11 idioms like shared_ptr do not in general simplify lifetime management as this is the central theme being taught in c++. Is this a new general consensus? I have no problem struggling with the counting problems, but the idiom must in the long run resolve some major lifetime management problems in large systems like mine.

Answer (score 1):

No one has substantively weighed in on what I am doing, so I applied what I know so far about smart pointers: never go out of scope with more than one strong ref to the object or it won't destruct. Seems obvious now.

RESULT FROM IMPLEMENTING MY RECURSIVE PARSER USING SHARED_PTR

Success! FYI, here are the practices I used in solving the problem:

1) Start out programming a project in general not considering using weak ptrs. Make everything shared ptr. You need your attention squarely fixed on solving the project at hand without distractions. That is, don't try to optimize until you are done. This keeps you from engineering code-weirdness in due to ptr logic. BTW, the next time you will make a better estimate at the ownership properties each of what your objects should have at the outset.

2) Use a memory leak detector program. I always write in C++ MFC which automatically reports leaks and their memory blocks on each run so it is easy to track down the culprits.

3) When you are satisfied with your program, to get rid of the leaks, re-think the ownership of your objects so that there is 1 strong reference to the top object you want to automatically be destroyed at the end of your execution path.

One side-effect of using shared_ptr is the code got simpler. This is what was promised us by the c++11 designers and it's true. The error messages forced me to think through at compiler-time the ownership of each object. Gone are the days when I, in the destructor, would just test to see if a pointer is non null and do a delete and hope the other threads are finished.

One Caveat: I have not implemented try/catch around weak_ptrs that have expired. I need to do this for production code. I'll report back here when I do.